# String representation of a polynomial

Tags: python, formatting, symbolic-math

We all know that math notation is idiosyncratic. Canonical representation of math objects often have irregular grammar rules to improve readability. For example we write a polynomial \$3x^3 + x^2\$ instead of more uniform but more verbose \$3x^3 + 1x^2 + 0x^1 + 0x^0\$. When a coefficient equals 0, you don't write the term, if the power equals \$1\$, you simply write \$x\$, and so on. So I wrote a simple program that outputs a string representation of a polynomial, given a list of coefficients:

```
def enumerate2(xs, start=0, step=1):
    for x in xs:
        yield (start, x)
        start += step

def poly(xs):
    """Return string representation of a polynomial.

    >>> poly([2,1,0])
    "2x^2 + x"
    """
    res = []
    for e, x in enumerate2(xs, len(xs)-1, -1):

        variable = 'x'

        if x == 1:
            coefficient = ''
        elif x == -1:
            coefficient = '-'
        else:
            coefficient = str(x)

        if e == 1:
            power = ''
        elif e == 0:
            power = ''
            variable = ''
        else:
            power = '^' + str(e)

        if x < 0:
            coefficient = '(' + coefficient
            power = power + ')'

        if x != 0:
            res.append(coefficient + variable + power)

    return ' + '.join(res)
```

`enumerate2` is a custom version of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) that [supports variable step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24290025/596361). The result looks like this:

```
>>> poly([2,0,3,-4,-3,2,0,1,10])
'2x^8 + 3x^6 + (-4x^5) + (-3x^4) + 2x^3 + x + 10'
```

How do I make this code more elegant and probably more generic? Oh, and the result is sub-optimal, as negative terms are enclosed in brackets, instead of changing the preceding plus sign to minus.

Answer (score 5):

Your `enumerate2` is a nice touch but I am not quite convinced that this is necessary : if you are to play with the length manually, you might as well compute the power from the index manually.

Also, if you were to handle the negative with a minus instead of the plus, you'd be able to get rid of the brackets. On the other hand, you cannot use `join` anymore which is a bit of a pain because it is a cool and efficient function.

Anyway, here's my try :

```
def poly(p, var_string='x'):
    res = ''
    first_pow = len(p) - 1
    for i, coef in enumerate(p):
        power = first_pow - i

        if coef:
            if coef < 0:
                sign, coef = (' - ' if res else '- '), -coef
            elif coef > 0: # must be true
                sign = (' + ' if res else '')

            str_coef = '' if coef == 1 and power != 0 else str(coef)

            if power == 0:
                str_power = ''
            elif power == 1:
                str_power = var_string
            else:
                str_power = var_string + '^' + str(power)

            res += sign + str_coef + str_power 
    return res
```

and the corresponding output :

```
2x^8 + 3x^6 - 4x^5 - 3x^4 + 2x^3 + x + 10
```

**Bug found**

As I was looking at my original implementation, I found a bug which happens to be in yours too : try with `[1,1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: `return` instead of `print`

Comment: @Maarten Fabré indeed I've updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a simpler way to do this:

```
fmt = [
    [ "", "", "" ],
    [ "{c:+g}", "{sign:s}x", "{sign:s}x^{n:g}" ],
    [ "{c:+g}", "{c:+g}x", "{c:+g}x^{n:g}" ]
]

def term(c, n):
    return fmt[cmp(abs(c),1)+1][cmp(n,1)+1].format(sign="- +"[cmp(c,0)+1], c=c, n=n)

def poly(xs):
    return "".join(term(xs[i],len(xs)-i-1) for i in xrange(len(xs)))

def suppsign(s):
    return s.lstrip('+')

print suppsign(poly([1,1,1]))
```

The `term` function takes a coefficient and power value and uses the characteristics of those two to select the appropriate format string to generate a string representing an individual term.

The `poly` function uses a list comprehension to efficiently concatenate the string for each term.

The `suppsign` function simply removes the leading `+` from the resulting string if desired.

Comment: `suppsign(poly([1,1,1]))` would be better written as `poly([1,1,1]).lstrip('+')`

Comment: You don't have to use square brackets inside `join`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18212201/596361

Comment: I would also remove `:g` and change `:+g` to `:+`, as these are equivalent, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 2):

## `enumerate2`

Here you can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) or `reversed`

```
for e, x in enumerate2(xs, len(xs)-1, -1):
```

becomes

```
for e, x in zip(itertools.count(len(xs)-1, -1), xs):
```

or

```
for e, x in zip(reversed(range(len(xs)), xs):
```

## `continue`

You can skip to the next iteration in the for-loop easier by doing instead of `if x != 0: ...`:

```
if x == 0:
    continue
```

at the beginning of the loop

## split functions

```
def coefficient(x):
    """returns the string representation of `x`.""" 
    if x == 1:
        return ""
    if x == -1:
        return "-"
    return str(x)
```

## sting multiplication and `bool`

for the power part, you can use string multiplication and the fact `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`

```
result = coefficient(x) + variable + f"^{e}" * (e != 1)
```

## f-string

Since python 3.6, you can do `f"({result})" if x < 0 else result` instead of

```
        coefficient = '(' + coefficient
        power = power + ')'
```

## yield

Instead of keeping a list of results, you can yield the intermediate terms. This

```
def poly2(xs, variable="x"):
    if set(xs) == {0}:
        yield "0"
        return
    for e, x in zip(reversed(range(len(xs))), xs):
        if x == 0:
            continue
        if e == 0:
            result = str(x)
        else:
            result = coefficient(x) + variable + f"^{e}" * (e != 1)
        yield f"({result})" if x < 0 else result
```

> ```
>  " + ".join(poly2((1,-1,0,)))
> ```

```
'x^2 + (-x)'
```

Comment: Why `(e not in {1, 0})`? Is that a legacy of an earlier version where the previous `if e == 0` special case didn't exist? Or was the special case supposed to be removed when you added the `(e not in {1, 0})`?

Comment: You are correct. This is a relic of a previous version that had no influence, but is not necessary anymore.